# iPhone Facebook application crash after authorize

Tags: iphone, facebook

I make application using FBConnect.

I have take viewbase iPhone application

main delegate class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    return [[viewController.view facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

controller class

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];

    Facebook* facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"160696837308609"];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
}
```

when I run application it open a facebook view for allowing. When I click on allow then a black screen comes and application crashes.

When I restart application then webview comes with message that "You are already authorized click Okay". After clicking OK same thing happen and app crashes.

Comment: I comment the line in delegate class  return [[viewController.view facebook] handleOpenURL:url];. . . . .then it works ok and come back to main screen can we define some method after success or failure of login authenticate

Comment: and also how I will get access token

Comment: How we implement facebook delegates

Comment: Does the controller class implement adhere to the facebook (FBSessionDelegate) delegate interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment the line in delegate class return
`[[viewController.view facebook] handleOpenURL:url];`
then it works ok and come back to main screen